# Orthogonal projections in an AW* algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $\{P_n\}$ is an orthogonal family of projections in an AW$^*$-algebra $A$, and $\sup\{P_1,P_2, \ldots\}=P$. Suppose  $T\in A$ and  $T=PTP$ and, for every n, $P_nT=TP_n = 0$. Must  $T=0$?